# ¿Cuál es la versión más antigua de .net (asp.net) que puedo publicar en el IIS de un WS2012R2?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

Tengo varios sitios web desarrollados en diferentes versiones de `Visual Studio` (y por ende en diferentes versiones de `.net` desde la 1.0), `VS2002`, `Vs2003`, `VS2005`, `Vs2008`, bueno hasta la 2015, todos los sitios web que fueron desarrollados desde `VS2002` hasta `VS2008` se encuentran publicados en un `Windows Server 2003`.

Ahora bien la pregunta es, ¿cuáles de estos sitios los puedo publicar en `Windows Server 2012 R2`? Bueno me imagino que a partir de `.net 2.0` (`VS2005`) puedo hacerlo, pero mi duda es sobre `.net 1.0` y `.net 1.1` (`VS2002` y `VS2003`), alguien podría colaborarme al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La verdad es que recomendaria que si tienes algun codigo en .net 1.0 veas de planear una migracion de version de forma urgente, no deberia ser complejo, con solo abrir el codigo en una version mas nueva del VS y cambiando la version del framework deberia compilar correctamente ya que con esa version primigenia de .net la funcionlidad deberia ser muy basica.

Respecto a implementar .net 1.1 en Win 2012 no vas a poder realizarlo, no esta soportado

[Ejecutar aplicaciones de .NET Framework 1.1 en Windows 8, Windows 8.1 o Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/hh925570(v=vs.110).aspx)

quizas si instalas .net 3.5 en el servidor este pueda ejecutar versiones compiladas con .net anteriores

Comment: Gracias Leandro, a ver si retomas tu blog que era super para aprender, y mas aun, yo digo que deberías dedicarte a escribir libros, uf.... vendiéndolo como digital a bajo costo te arias millonario y ayudarías a muuuucha gente como lo hiciste hasta ahora.